# React.js render function error, expecting a semi-colon at the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Im working on a content section of a news blog, which is being powered by the 'newsapi' and matches post using url to each post content, I need help reviewing the code and fixing the bug. I encountered this render function error:

```
Line 9:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

   7 |   constructor(props){
   8 |     super(props);
>  9 |     render(props) {
     |                   ^
  10 |       const post = this.props;
  11 |       const validUrl = post.match.params.url;
```

This is the complete code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    render(props) {

      const post = this.props;
      const validUrl = post.match.params.url;

      const postcard = (post) => {
          if (validUrl === post.url) {
            return (
              <div>
                <div class="card card-cascade wider reverse">
                  <div class="view view-cascade overlay">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src={post.urlToImage} alt="Card image cap"/>
                    <a href="#!">
                      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><strong>{post.title}</strong></h4>
                    <h6 class="font-weight-bold indigo-text py-2">{post.author}</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">{post.content}</p>
                    <p><a class="px-2 fa-lg li-ic">Source:{post.author}</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>)
              </div>
            );
          } else {
            return <div><h1>Page Not Found</h1></div>;
          }
        };


      return (
        <div class="container">
            {postcard}
        </div>
      );

    };
  }
}
 
export default Post;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to do this:

```js
class Post {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    ...

  }
  // define this outside the constructor
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the render function outside the constructor.

```
class Post {
  constructor() {
  }

  render() {
  }
}
```